# Converting nvarchar to varchar: Anyone have any performance metrics?

Tags: ssis

I'm working an SSIS package where every character field is an nvarchar, and since the data is all for clients in US-Ohio I'll assume for the moment that varchar would work fine.

Question:  Would anyone have any performance metrics on the difference in speed of..

- Instead of importing all columns as nvarchar's...
- Create a Derived Column to convert all to char's?

I'm aware of the size differences of nvarchar vs. char, this question is about the speed of which SSIS converts to char's.

Thanks in advance.
Jim

Comment: To restate, the source data provider is serving nvarchar data. The content of the data itself contains no internationalization. Therefore... what? How fast does SSIS convert unicode to non-unicode (code page 1252)? Do you have any gauge of the average length of the strings? How about the ratio of NULLs to non-NULLs? Can we assume the box will have sufficient memory to prevent paging to disk? Are we dealing with any stream/max data types?

Comment: What you will do if client in US-Ohio will become a russian, german and etc.

Comment: btw I have a more SalesForce-specific version of this question here.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60076/is-there-a-smaller-soql-character-data-type-then-sql-server-nvarchar-for-sf-char

Answer (score -1):

Use a data conversion task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=en-US&k=k(sql12.dts.designer.dataconversiontrans.f1)&rd=true

This will give you access to the original and converted fields in the output.

In my opinion it's the easiest way to go as well.

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question, which is related to the performance aspects of a data-conversion.

Comment: It does actually in my opinion. I have provided an additional option for data conversion with a sited link to MSDN witch also contains information regarding the performance differences between data conversion types.

Comment: It does not answer the question, as it's really nothing more than what I've stated in the question (other than Derived Column/Data Conversion), and I'm not real big on 'Here's a link, now you fish for the answer' type solutions.